# How can I add a login/logout link in the sub-nav of my website?

Tags: login, navigation

Using the code below I was able to get a login/logout button working on my navigation. This code makes it so that it displays on my main navigation and I just wanted it to appear as a sub-nav item when you hover our "Users" link.

Is this possible by making any changes to the code below?

Thank you!

````
function my_account_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->primary-menu == 'locations-divided-menu-right-navigation') { //change your theme registered menu name to suit
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) ) .'">Log Out</a></li>'; //change logout link, here it goes to 'shop', you may want to put it to 'myaccount'
    }
    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->primary-menu == 'locations-divided-menu-right-navigation') {//change your theme registered menu name to suit
        $items .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">Log In</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}```
````